# How to be notified of a Teams message through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to figure out how to use Microsoft Graph API to get notified of incoming Teams messages.

I easily find the endpoint to send a message.
[Create chatMessage in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

But I do not find an endpoint to get API messages, either via polling or better via a web hook.

Is there a way to get a user incoming messages via REST (assuming proper authentication) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get change notifications (i.e. set up a webhook) for Teams channel messages using the beta endpoint of Graph. See the [subscription beta documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/subscription?view=graph-rest-beta) and ["Create subscription" beta documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) for a list of supported resources, including `chatMessage`.

Comment: @Yves If you feel your question was answered, please accept the answer so that the question is marked appropriately. Thanks!